# Transactions occurring at the same exact time create bad select results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL database that keeps track of items in an inventory. Items have a quantity and can be checked out.

I have a table of **Items** that contain an OnHandQty and an OutQty.

Whenever a check out occurs, I store a record in my **ItemHistory** table and update the quantity values in my **Items** table to reflect the change.

This works great until lots of transactions are being sent to the server at the same time.

**My checkout query looks like this:**

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    DECLARE @OnHand [int]
    DECLARE @Out [int]

    SELECT @OnHand = QtyOnHand, @Out = QtyOut
    FROM [Item] 

    IF (((-@qty) + @OnHand) >= 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[ItemHistory] (...)
            OUTPUT Inserted.ItemID
            VALUES(...)

            UPDATE [Item]
            SET 
            QtyOnHand = @OnHand - @qty,
            QtyOut = @Out + @qty
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END
COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

**The issue occurs here:**

```
SELECT @OnHand = QtyOnHand, @Out = QtyOut
FROM [Item]
```

The server sometimes begins two transactions at the exact same time. This causes the **@OnHand** and **@Out** variables to be the exact same in two separate transactions. This is not good, as these are supposed to represent the CURRENT totals. Which they technically do, as the server has not had time to update the **Item** table at this point.

I need this select to get the absolute current quantities for this to work.

Is there a way to prevent transactions from occurring at the exact same time? Or is there a better way to handle this process?

Comment: @DaleBurrell This seems to have worked! I was not aware you could do this. I put the `with (tablockx)` here: `SELECT @OnHand = QtyOnHand, @Out = QtyOut
    FROM [Item] WITH (tablockx)`. Is that the statement you would recommend?

Comment: I'm impressed you found a way to reproduce that issue. Concurrency can be quite a pain to test.

Comment: I have a routine in my application that checks-out X number of items. I noticed that when I did a large amount of items, the OnHand total would sometimes be less than the number of check-out records in the history table. Then I found multiple date-time values in the history that were the exact same. I figured it had to be a timing issue with the first select statement getting the current quantities. Your solution was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways to handle concurrency issues in SQL Server are:

1) Take an exclusive table lock `with (tablockx)` on the table e.g.

```
SELECT @OnHand = QtyOnHand, @Out = QtyOut FROM [Item] WITH (tablockx)
```

2) Use [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create a single user block of code.

Note: Keep in mind that by forcing single user access to this block of code you are reducing the performance throughput of your database. So you want to keep these sort of locks as short as possible.